# How To Parse the Response Header of a Youtube Build API Query (python flask)

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I'm calling the YouTube API via:

```
youtube = build(
    'youtube', 'v3',
    developerKey=API_KEY)

videoList = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part="id, contentDetails, snippet, status", 
    maxResults=50,
    playlistId=PLAYLIST_ID
).execute()

return videoList
```

which returns a dictionary of items I can parse.

But I'm trying to parse the response header so I can extract the `nextPageToken` to get the next page...
yet can't find anything about how to extract this using the above method.

Any tips much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to remark is that the page token, that is to be passed to the next call of the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint, is not to be found in the HTTP response header resulted upon the previous API call.

According to the official doc of `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint, the [JSON response obtained](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response) from invoking the endpoint looks like:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    playlistItem Resource
  ]
}
```

Now, it's clear that the page token you need for to implement [API result set pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) is available within the endpoint response itself -- not within the HTTP response header (which is another thing) -- as value of the property [`nextPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#nextPageToken).

But, from the point of view of an user of Google's APIs Client Library for Python (this inferred from your source code shown), API result set pagination looks a bit more *pythonic* (i.e. you need not use `nextPageToken` explicitly):

```py
request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part = 'id,contentDetails,snippet,status',
    playlistId = PLAYLIST_ID,
    maxResults = 50
)
playlistItems = []

while request:
    response = request.execute()
    playlistItems.extend(response['items'])
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
        request, response)

return playlistItems
```

Note that this code does not return `videos` but `playlistItems` on purpose. The JSON object resulted upon the call `request.execute()` is not a [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), but a `PlaylistItems.list` response object as quoted above.

The inner `items` array of this latter object contains all the metadata pertaining to the entries contained in the playlist identified by `PLAYLIST_ID`; those entries are [PlaylistItems resource objects](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource). The code above uses `playlistItems.extend` for adding to `playlistItems` only the objects referring the items of the respective playlist.

---

**Documentation of Google's *APIs Client Library For Python***

The main site documenting the client library is: [Google API Client Library for Python Docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/). Its source is public, to be found within the [client library's public repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/) under the directory [`docs`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs).

Pagination is illustrated there too, under the page [How to... Use Pagination](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/pagination.html).

Also interesting is to see the [YouTube Data API's list of all instance methods](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/youtube_v3.html). Your method of interest -- `playlistItems.list_next` -- [is documented](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/youtube_v3.playlistItems.html#list_next) too.

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  Just for my understanding...where do you find information about the list_next method?

Comment: Yes, of course: see my updated answer above.